# Did "pertinacious" and "pertinent" come from the same origin?

Tags: etymology

From dictionary.com:

**pertinacious**

meaning:

1. holding tenaciously to a purpose, course of action, or opinion;
   resolute.
2. stubborn or obstinate.
3. extremely or objectionably persistent.

while

**pertinent**

1. pertaining or relating directly and significantly to the matter at
   hand; relevant.

I can't find anything in common in terms of their meaning. Although,

> Pertinent:from Latin pertinēns, from pertinēre to pertain
>
> Pertinacious:1620-30; pertinaci(ty) + -ous

And **pertinent** is related to **pertinence**, which looks similar to **pertinacious**. Is it a coincidence?

Let me know if these questions are not constructive, I'll stop posting. By the way, I'm studying vocabulary for English test so I'm trying to find a way to memorize words that look similar otherwise I'll have to do it all by rote.

Comment: Here's [a text from 1816](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=228TAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA265&dq=tenacious+pertinacious&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TDFbVaefNsO17gb6qYCYDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=tenacious%20pertinacious&f=false) setting out usage differences. But personally, I wouldn't bother wasting brain cells remembering ***pertinacious*** at all. It's very rarely used today, and usually when it *is* used it's just a pretentious alternative to ***tenacious*** anyway. Besides, I doubt it would be likely to turn up in a vocabulary test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They actually both derive from ***PER and TENET***

***Pertinacious***:( 1620s, from pertinacy (late 14c.; see pertinacity):

> - pertinacity
> - c. 1500, from Middle French pertinacité (early 15c.), from Old French pertinace "obstinate, stubborn," ***from Latin pertinacem (nominative pertinax) "very firm, tenacious, steadfast, persevering,"*** from per- "very" (see per) + tenax (see tenacious). It drove out earlier pertinacy (late 14c.).
> - tenacious (adj.)
>     c. 1600, from Latin stem of tenacity + -ous.
> - tenacity (n.)
>     early 15c., from Middle French ténacité (14c.) and directly from Latin tenacitas "an act of holding fast," from tenax (genitive tenacis) "holding fast, gripping, clingy; firm, steadfast," ***from tenere "to hold" (see tenet)***.

***Pertinent***:

> - late 14c., from Anglo-French purtinaunt (late 13c.), Old French partenant (mid-13c.) and directly from Latin pertinentem (nominative pertinens) "pertaining," present participle of pertinere ***"to relate, concern" (see pertain)***.
> - ***pertain*** (v.):early 14c., from Old French partenir "to belong to" and directly from Latin pertinere "to reach, stretch; relate, have reference to; belong, be the right of; be applicable," ***from per- "through" (see per) + tenere "to hold" (see tenet)***.

form Etymonline

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually yes.

Latin (per)tinax and (per)tinens are both related to the verb tenere "to hold". pertinax is literally "holding fast to something".